# Proportionality of Einstein tensor with 3-space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I am required to solve the following problem:

> Consider an observer at point *p* with 4-velocity **u**. Prove that $G_{ab}u^au^b$ is proportional to the scalar curvature R of the local 3-space of the observer at that point.

They give as well a recommended strategy:

> Consider the Riemann-tensor at *p*. Use the projection operator $P_a^b=g_a^b+u_au^b$ to project all indices to the 3-space of the observer. This is now the Riemann tensor of that 3-space. Contract the indices to obtain R (you can use that **PP**=**P**, refering to the projector).

I also need to compare, but I can do that on my own. My main issue here is that "use the projection operator to project ALL its indices". I do not know if I need to do it in 3 different expressions o I must apply the projector 3 times to achieve that. I am probably making several mistakes regarding the contractions.

The metric has a signature (-+++) and **u** is a normalized timelike vector.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify what my problem is about, I will write exactly what I mean. It seems like multiplying 3 times by **P** is useless, as I will just obtain **P** anyways. Doing it on different expressions may be the correct thing, but doesn't that mean that I will have 3 different Riemann tensors?
Which of these should be?

- $P.P.P.R^a_{bcd}$
- $P.R^a_{bcd}$ 3 times

Comment: Apply the projector to the Riemann tensor *four* times, once on each index.

Comment: Neither of your quotes says "use the projector to lower ALL its indices". Where did that come from? The projector as written does not lower indices.

Comment: @G.Smith I messed up with that sentence. I mean to project all indices, not lower them. I will correct that.
Anyway, how do I apply it? On different equations?

Comment: In *one* equation.

Comment: I found an article regarding exactly your question: https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ahep/2018/6509045.pdf